# read Cordova file transfer params

Tags: java, cordova, rest, multipartform-data, file-transfer

I am uploading files with cordova file transfer and i read that request with a rest service. Here is an example.

http://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-upload-example

I want to pass some parameters but i do not know how to read them from the upload method that i have in my rest service.

The way i pass thos parameters from file transfer is with

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Any help please?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

They are sent as POST, so you can get them with

```
$_POST["value1"];
$_POST["value2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read them adding additional method parameters using the annotations `@FormDataParam("value1")` and `@FormDataParam("value2")`. Method signature should look like this:

```
 public Response uploadFile(  
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,  
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @FormDataParam("value1") String value1,
        @FormDataParam("value2") String value2) {  ...
```